# scanf converting the £ charatcter to œ in a string

Tags: c

I am trying to read an input string containing `£` character and other usual character using `scanf` , but the `£` character is getting converted to `œ` .

Can you please help to resolve the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char a[20];

    printf(" Enter the string");
    scanf("%s",a);
}
```

The above code snippet is a part of the code , I am trying to give the input string as `"Surya£07"`, and passing the `a` to another function.

I am trying this on the visual studio 2010 and seeing that the value in the `scanf` is `Suryaœ07`.

Comment: Can you please help by sharing code?

Comment: Please post your code,.. So that we can help you buddy?,..

Comment: done that, please check

Comment: Learn to indent code; I did it for you now.

Comment: It's not for the program but due to the terminal that you're trying to paste the text into or that is displaying it.

Comment: How you are getting this '£' as input in your string?

Comment: The scanf is taking the input , and the value that is being passed is different .

Comment: try setting your system keyboard setting to UK english, it many be using another region

Comment: to get £ in the string i am using <alt+156> on keyboard

Comment: no im not doing any Ctrl+c/Ctrl+v , I am typing it on the keyboard

Comment: @user3222445 Are you entering the input for the program and also seeing its result from the same terminal window and command prompt? E.g. run `cmd.exe` and repeat the same experiment without visual studio. When I type <alt+156> in the command prompt I get `œ` by the way.

Comment: Use [<alt+163>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound_sign#Windows_PC)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
TCHAR a[20];  
wscanf(L"%s", a);

wprintf(L"%s", a);
```

You have to define `_UNICODE` before running the code.

Comment: I tried the same but still not working.

Comment: And can you please brief me what to define in _UNICODE

Comment: If your code compiles and dont need any headers just change `TCHAR` with `unsigned short`